# Conditional DynamoDb Queries

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDb table called Users.  I am trying to execute a very simple query where the user's last name is like 'John*' (Johnson, Johnston, Johnny, etc), however I cannot find a very straight forward example.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
public class DynamoDbUsersTest extends ApplicationTest {
      @Autowired
      private DynamoDb dynamoDb;

      private Table usersTable = dynamoDb.getTable("Users");

      public void getUsersByLastNameContainsTest(){
          //userTable.contains(user.getLastName());  // No such method.
          userTable.scan(new ScanFilter("lastName").contains("John");
          ...
      }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I tried looking at the `Query` Object, but I'm not sure it'll do what I need it to.

I begrudgingly had to use the `Scan` Object to make this work, however it does a full table scan with each query.


Has anyone found a better/faster way of searching with partial values?


Would the following be faster?

```
public class DynamoDbUsersTest extends ApplicationTest {
      @Autowired
      private DynamoDb dynamoDb;

      private Table usersTable = dynamoDb.getTable("Users");

      public void getUsersByLastNameContainsTest(){
          userTable.query(new QueryFilter("lastName").contains("John");
          ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Substring matching is something done well by ElasticSearch. I suggest you turn on your DynamoDB table's stream and index your items/documents in an AWS ElasticSearch cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `ScanSpec` using `contains` to match the string partially.

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("tablename");

        Map<String, Object> attributeValueMap = new HashMap<>();
        attributeValueMap.put(":lastNameValue", "John");

        ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withFilterExpression("contains (lastName,:lastNameValue)")
                .withValueMap(attributeValueMap);
        IteratorSupport<Item, ScanOutcome> scanOutcome = null;

        scanOutcome = table.scan(scanSpec).iterator();

while (scanOutcome.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Output ==============>" + scanOutcome.next().toJSON());
        }
```

**Edit:-**

As mentioned in other answers, you can use `QuerySpec` if you know the hash key and `lastname` is not defined as hash key. Also, you can use the `contains` on `FilterExpression` only. In other words, it can't be used on `KeyConditionExpression`.

`QuerySpec` needs KeyConditionExpression which will only support equality operator on  hash key attribute. And then on `FilterExpression`, you can use `contains` on non-key attributes.

Comment: thank you.  How is this any different than what I have above?

Comment: Instead of using a `ScanSpec`, I wonder if you could use a `QuerySpec` instead to avoid the full table scans

Comment: `QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec(new QueryFilter("lastName").contains("john"));

table.query(querySpec);`

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `contains` as part of a query, only a scan; but if you only care about results *starting* with a particular value, then you can use the `begins_with` query operator: `begins_with (a, substr)` (where `a` is your key name). For this to work, the key must be a sort key, not a partition key. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html

Comment: Thanks.  I will check today and make sure the key is a sorted key.  So, given that I have two keys (`contract_number` and `vendor_name`), is it possible to only a single key, say `vendor_name`, without having to use the other?

Comment: I don't believe so - a range key is optional, but a partition key is mandatory. In this case, I think you'd need to specify `contract_number=x` as well as `begins_with(vendor_name, john)`. The partition key doesn't have to be unique, but the combination of partition key and range key must be.

I''m pretty sure that with these restrictions, DynamoDB is not a good choice of database for your use case - it really only handles the case where you know what you want to find, it does not handle traditional DB queries so well. You will probably be better off using RDS or similar.

Comment: I was able to get this up and running using `contractNumber` as my partition key and `vendorName` as my secondary key.  I then run a scan for what I'm looking for.  It's able to handle the 70K records in 2MS  :)